# SuggestAppend Combobox shows doesnt show duplicate names (if exists)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox of Names. There can be person with similar name. Now if I set AutoCompleteMode Property of ComboBox to SuggestAppend and if there are two records with same name, the SuggestAppend DropDown list shows only the first value (name).

**Actual List:**

[image: Notice two RatanTata names here]Notice two **`Ratan Tata`** names here

**Suggest Append:**

When I type **R** in comboBox, it shows only one value of **`RatanTata`**

[image: I get only one Name in the List]

So now I get two problems due to this.

**`Problem 1:`** As said, we see only one name in the SuggestAppend DropDownlist.

**`Problem 2:`** 
Depending on the selected item in combobox, other controls on the form (textbox, listbox, combobox) shows the respective data of that selected contact.

Now in the scenario of duplicate names, when I manually select the **2nd `Ratan Tata`** name, I see the details of **2nd `Ratan Tata`** in respective controls on the form. But as and when I move out of the combobox (using tab or mouse click on other control) the respective data in the other controls changes to the value of **1st `Ratan Tata`**.

I hope I am clear in explanation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you append any unique identifier to the Name? It should work then.

Comment: Sandeep G B: What type of unique identifier?

Comment: Think you got caught with what MSDN says *If there are duplicate entries in the maintained source, automatic completion behaves unpredictably.* [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode.aspx)

Comment: @Niraj, unique identifier could be some name/user id or any such unique number to identify different names. I am not sure if you can hide it after appending.

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Always at my rescue :). Thank you. So it means I m left with no option if there are duplicate entries.

Comment: @Niraj hope this leads you to somewhere [Link](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Q_26645697.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should **use Suggest** instead of using SuggestAppend. Below is an explanation from MSDN when to use Suggest and when SuggestAppend:

None:           Disables the automatic completion feature for the ComboBox and TextBox controls.

**Suggest**:    Displays the auxiliary drop-down list associated with the edit control. This drop-down is **populated with one or more suggested** completion strings.

Append:         Appends the remainder of the **most likely candidate string** to the existing characters, highlighting the appended characters.

**SuggestAppend**:  Applies both Suggest and Append options.